# Combine 2 matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

There is:

```
a = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10];   %(10x1 double)
b = [1;3;4;5;6;9];   %(6x1 double)
```

I hope to combine `a` and `b`. So my expected result is:

[image]

I think may be use conditional or first import zeros(10 2)? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1: Conditional Checking**

Checks if the values in the arrays match before filling the combined array. If they match both columns are filled. If they do not match the `"NaN"` undefined term is placed in the array. The variable `Index` that controls the scanning for array `b` is only incremented upon finding a match between both arrays.

```
%Method 1: Conditional%
a = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10];  
b = [1; 3; 4; 5; 6; 9];   

%Creating a result array of the same length as array "a"%
Combined_Array = zeros(length(a),2);

%Copying the first column into the result array "Combined_Array"%
for Row = 1: +1: length(a)
Combined_Array(Row,1) = a(Row,1);    
end

%Padding the array "b" with zeroes to match the length of array "a"%
b = [b; zeros(length(a) - length(b),1)];


Index = 1;
for Row = 1: +1: length(a)

%If the values in arrays "a" and "b" do not match%
if a(Row,1) ~= b(Index,1)
Combined_Array(Row,2) = "NaN";
Index = Index - 1;
end

%If the values in arrays "a" and "b" match%
if a(Row,1) == b(Index,1)
Combined_Array(Row,2) = b(Index,1);
end

Index = Index + 1;
    
end

%Printing the result%
Combined_Array
```

**Method 2: Concatenation and Filling Arrays**

Fill in the arrays where the undefined term `"NaN"` is expected and concatenate the rest of the content accordingly. Using `horzcat` will concatenate columns together side by side. (`vertcat` concantates rows on top of one another)

```
%Method 2: Hard-Coded and Concatenation%
a = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10];  
b = [1; 3; 4; 5; 6; 9];   

b = [b(1); "NaN"; b(2:5);"NaN"; "NaN"; b(6); "NaN"];


Combined_Array = horzcat(a,b);
```